# How to compare only last few row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have my excel is look like this:

```
      A      B       C       D       E       F       G
1:  5/13/14 32451   2.367   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
2:  5/14/14 32454   2.602   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
3:  5/14/14 32454                   
4:  5/15/14 32448   2.602   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
5:  5/15/14 32453   2.602   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
6:  5/15/14 32451                   
7:  5/15/14 32466   2.602   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
8:  5/15/14 32426   2.602   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
9:  5/16/14 32539   2.602   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
10: 5/16/14 32539                   

     H    I    J     K
12: Yes  Yes   No    No
```

I was looking a formula to compare the last 5 data on:

- column D whether is there any data is on true and it will return Yes on H12, if data is     false than it will return No on H12
- column E whether is there any data is on true and it will return Yes on I12, if data is false than it will return No on I12
- column F whether is there any data is on true and it will return Yes on J12, if data is false than it will return No on J12
- column G whether is there any data is on true and it will return Yes on K12, if data is false than it will return No on k12

Currently I have my formula in `H12 will be IF(COUNTIF(D1:D100,"TRUE*")=0,"No","Yes"))`
but this is count all row from D1: D100,  was wondering is there any way just to count the last 5 rows? 
They will be many data will keep added in, so is there any possible to make a formula to just count the last 5 rows data only?

==================================================================================
here will be my data:

`A         B       C       D       E       F       G
    1:5/15/14   32448   2.602   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
    2:5/15/14   32451   2.602   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
    3:5/15/14   32466   2.602   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
    4:5/15/14   32426

    5:5/15/14   32426   2.602   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
    6:5/16/14   32539   2.602   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
    7:5/16/14   32539   2.602   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE`

as the picture you can see, on the D10 is True, so which meant that on H12 and H13 will return Yes but not No.

On H12 I am using this formula:
 `=IF(SUM(--(OFFSET(D$1,COUNTA($A:$A)-5,0,5)=TRUE))>0,"Yes","No")`

On H13 I am using this formula:  `=IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(D$1,COUNTA($A:$A)-5,0,5),TRUE)=0,"No","Yes")`

Can you show me how to modify but checking the date? Sorry...I am still learning on Array formula... >.<

Comment: If new data added, it will not change ><

Comment: but vba is just for function right? like it use on any button function?

Answer (score 0):

If your last five rows is referenced in *Column A*, try this:

`=IF(SUM(--(OFFSET(D$1,COUNTA($A:$A)-5,0,5)=TRUE))>0,"Yes","No")` for *Cell H12*.

Entered in *H12* as *Array Formula* by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Then autofill or copy to *I12, J12 and K12*.

**Edit1:** Actually, you can also use your formula like this:

`=IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(D$1,COUNTA($A:$A)-5,0,5),TRUE)=0,"No","Yes")`

No need *Array Formula* really. Just the dynamically changing range provided by *Offset*.
Then just copy to remaining cells (I12, J12 and K12).

**Important:** The criteria *TRUE* can be String or Boolean (in my case I used Boolean for testing).
 Adjust to suit how you've written your data.

**Edit2:** If you want to evaluate based on *Date on ColumnA*.

`=IF(SUM(IF(($A$1:$A$11>=DATEVALUE("5/13/2014"))*($A$1:$A$11<=DATEVALUE("5/14/2014"))<>0,IFERROR(--D$1:D$11,0),0))<>0,"Yes","No")`

Above formula works if *TRUE and FALSE* are Boolean type. It won't work otherwise.

**Result:**
[image]

So this will return *Yes* on H12 if there is *TRUE* on dates between 5/13/2014 and 5/14/2014.
Again, *ColumnA* value should be dates.

Comment: hi, I have tested on it, if the last data return true, it will not count on the last data, it only able to count when the last row is equal to false...can I ask how about the date? is there any possibility to compare the data which is fall between 5/13/14 to 5/14/14? for example if between 5/13/14 to 5/14/14, there is any data on column D return with True, than it will show Yes on H12.

Comment: It works fine on my end. I added Screen Shots. Can you show how your data is structured? As for comparing dates, yes it is possible. You can modify the array formula or use countifs if you're using excel 2007 and up.

Comment: can you check the question that I edit, when the last data is True, it will still return No...

Comment: @Kimberly ah so pnuts is right. You indeed want to check the last 5 data disregarding blanks. For the solution I posted to work, there should be no blanks based on what you describe.